# C# How can I get multiple values with request.form.getvalues from this select

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the select is a multiple selection:

```
<Label ID="LabelCelphoneBrand" runat="server" for="CelphoneBrand">Brand *</Label>
<select id="CelphoneBrand" tabindex="4" runat="server" name="CelphoneBrand" required multiple>
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
    <option value="Alcatel">Alcatel</option>
    <option value="Huawei">Huawei</option>
    <option value="HTC">HTC</option>
    <option value="Nokia">Nokia</option>
    <option value="Sony">Sony</option>
    <option value="BlackBerry">BlackBerry</option>
    <option value="Motorola">Motorola</option>
</select>
```

I want to get all the values that the user selects and send them over to me via email:

```
email.Body = Request.Form.GetValues("CelphoneBrand");
```

This keeps getting me `System.String[]` instead of the actual options, if you need more info or more of my code let me know just trying to keep it clean and brief.

Comment: `GetValues` will return a string array, if you want its values use `email.Body = String.Join(",", Request.Form.GetValues("CelphoneBrand"));`

Answer (score 3):

You see `System.String[]` because that is the object type that is being returned (slightly off topic but the implicit string conversion of any array is `"DataType[]"` since your array is of type `System.String` the implicit conversion returns `"System.String[]"`).  What you'll need to do is *enumerate* the  values:

```
string body = "";
foreach (string v in  Request.Form.GetValues("CelphoneBrand"))
{
  body += v + "\r\n" //the \r\n is a line break
}
email.Body = body
```